# Read string until newline

Tags: rust

I'm trying to grab the output from an ls command. How do I separate strings by the newline character? Currently my code looks like this:

```
let input = std::old_io::stdin().read_line().ok().expect("Failed to read line");

for c in input.chars() {
  if c == '\n' {
    break;
  } else {
    println!("{}", c);
  }
}
```

This isn't working at all and I am printing all characters including \n.

Comment: have you tried to print the integer representation of both \n and the newline character in the input.chars()?

Comment: what is this integer representation?

Comment: When debugging, it can be helpful to inspect values: try inserting `println!("{:?}", input);` and see what `input` actually is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [`lines`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines) method on `BufRead`. That function returns an iterator over all the lines of the buffer. You can get a `BufRead` from [`Stdin`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.lock) through the `lock` function. If you look at the documentation of `lines` you can see, that it will not return the newline char. Compare this to the `read_line` function which does return the newline char.

```
use std::io::BufRead;

fn main() {
    // get stdin handle
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    // lock it
    let lock = stdin.lock();
    // iterate over all lines
    for line in lock.lines() {
        // iterate over the characters in the line
        for c in line.unwrap().chars() {
            println!("{}", c);
        }
        println!("next line");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to understand what you actually want from your explanation, but if you want to read every line from the input without a newline character you can use `lines()` iterator. The following is the version for the new `std::io`:

```
use std::io::BufRead;

let input = std::io::stdin();
for line in input.lock().lines() {
    // here line is a String without the trailing newline
}
```